# Angular ng-repeat not loading images from server - always "pending"

Tags: angularjs, image, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code running with angular v1.4.7

```
<img ng-repeat="x in modules" style="float:left" ng-src="{{moduleImagePath(x)}}"/>
```

The images paths are created by moduleImagePath(x)  This function basically switches an image from a good status to a error status image which has _ERR appended to the image name:

```
$scope.moduleImagePath= function(item)
        {
            var name = item.name
            if (item.idx === 0)
                name = 'Master'

            if (item.isLost === 1 || item.state != 'Op')
            {
                return 'img/' + name + '_ERR.jpg'
            }
            else
            {
                return 'img/' + name + '.jpg'
            }
        }
```

When the view is displayed, a timer starts polling for a json update that contains the modules data.  Normally it is on a 500ms timer, however for debug I have made it 10 seconds.

The images never appear on screen, chrome inspector states that the images are loading but they are never requested at the webserver.  They remain as "pending indefinitely:

```
Master.jpg  (pending)       Other   0 B Pending 
Master_ERR.jpg  (pending)       Other   0 B Pending 
EL1124.jpg  (pending)       Other   0 B Pending 
EL1124_ERR.jpg  (pending)       Other   0 B Pending 
EL4024.jpg  (pending)       Other   0 B Pending 
EL4024_ERR.jpg  (pending)       Other   0 B Pending 
EL2624.jpg  (pending)       Other   0 B Pending 
EL2624_ERR.jpg  (pending)       Other   0 B Pending 
EL4008_ERR.jpg  (pending)       Other   0 B Pending 
EL4008.jpg  (pending)       Other   0 B Pending
```

The webserver is mongoose embedded in a C program running on localhost.

If I use the following code it works but of course needs to be handwritten for every use case:

```
<div ng-if="x.name == 'Master' && x.isLost === 0"> <img src="img/Master.jpg"/></div>
<div ng-if="x.name == 'Master' && x.isLost === 1"> <img src="img/Master_Err.jpg"/></div>
<div ng-if="x.name == 'EK1100' && x.isLost === 0"> <img src="img/EK1100.jpg"/></div>
<div ng-if="x.name == 'EK1100' && x.isLost === 1"> <img src="img/EK1100_Err.jpg"/></div>
<div ng-if="x.name == 'EL1124' && x.isLost === 0"> <img src="img/EL1124.jpg"/></div>
<div ng-if="x.name == 'EL1124' && x.isLost === 1"> <img src="img/EL1124_Err.jpg"/></div>
<div ng-if="x.name == 'EL2624' && x.isLost === 0"> <img src="img/EL2624.jpg"/></div>
<div ng-if="x.name == 'EL2624' && x.isLost === 1"> <img src="img/EL2624_Err.jpg"/></div>
<div ng-if="x.name == 'EL4008' && x.isLost === 0"> <img src="img/EL4008.jpg"/></div>
<div ng-if="x.name == 'EL4008' && x.isLost === 1"> <img src="img/EL4008_Err.jpg"/></div>
<div ng-if="x.name == 'EL4024' && x.isLost === 0"> <img src="img/EL4024.jpg"/></div>
<div ng-if="x.name == 'EL4024' && x.isLost === 1"> <img src="img/EL4024_Err.jpg"/></div>
```

It seems like the resources need to be pre-loaded before I can switch them around.  Should this be done via css or another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issues with your angularjs code.but you just to resolve your problem you can try out this way.

create an `ng-switch` just for `x.isLost` ( i know it is just a bool.still i prefer to use `ng-switch` instead of `ng-if`)

```
  <div  ng-switch on="x.isLost">
           <img src="img/{{x.name}}.jpg" ng-switch-when="0"/>
           <img src="img/{{x.name}}_ERR.jpg" ng-switch-when="1"/>
  </div>
```

And just to check, are you running your webpage through localhost or your ipaddress ? sometimes when i try to access my webpage using by my IP i run into such kind of issues.